# Vector magnitude notation

Tags: notation, vectors, physics

Is the follow equality true? $$\left| \overrightarrow {u}\right| =u$$ I wonder, because on AP Physics formula sheets, sometimes the magnitude of a vector is clearly denoted, while other times the quantity is written as scalar with no vector arrow.

Comment: You should judge its nature by the background of the question

Comment: This is a common convention, yes, but surely the formula sheet indicates as much. It is not an equality so much as a definition of a piece of notation.

Comment: It is a constant struggle in math, let alone physics, to get people to use notation which is not too cumbersome but readily understood. For a significant percentage of questions on this site, more effort is required to figure out what is being asked than to provide the answer.

Comment: The simple heuristic when it comes to such issues of notation is: If they use it like a scalar, it's a scalar; if they use it like a vector, it's a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking it's false. The barrel/double barrel around the vector should be used.

Comment: I agree, but physicists sometimes have notational conventions of their own,